# Simulate stationary VAR(p)

Tags: time-series, simulation, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

I would like to simulate a stationary VAR(p) coefficient matrix. However, I only found the following (inefficient) solution:

1. Simulate a coefficient matrix (n x n*p) drawing each coefficient
   from a standard normal;
2. Re-write the model in companion form;
3. Check whether the module of the eigenvalues is lower than one: stop if that's the case, start again otherwise.

Ideally, I would like to rescale the coefficient matrix so that it is always representing a stationary VAR(p) process. Any idea?

PS: For simplicity, I fixed the var-cov matrix of the residuals to be a (n x n) identity matrix.